# How to compress inline Javascript in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, yui-compressor

I would like to know if it is possible to compress via yui compressor in Symfony2 an inline javascript twig file.
the twig file contains js code as `<script>/%JS code%/</script>`
The doc states that it works for .js files but didn't mention the inline javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Allow me to tell you how I finally did it: 

Install the bundle : 
https://github.com/nibsirahsieu/SalvaJshrinkBundle
after that use the tag jshrink

```
<script type="text/javascript">{% jshrink %}
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // ...
    });
{% endjshrink %}</script>
```

PS: if you're not using symfony you can download the library: https://github.com/tedivm/JShrink

Comment: Note that you can use this without Symfony via `$twig->addExtension(new \Salva\JshrinkBundle\Twig\Extension\JshrinkExtension)`.